# Vector losing reference to entries after function to add to vector finishes

Tags: c++, entity-framework, vector

I am implementing an Entity Component System and am having trouble when I am attempting to add a Component to an Entity. The structure of doing so is as follows:

Below will find an Entity with an ID of 0, and add a Position component to it.

```
m_entityManager->addComponentToEntityID(0, ComponentManager::POSITION);

void EntityManager::addComponentToEntityID(unsigned int entityID, ComponentManager::ComponentType componentType)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> tempEntity;

    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < m_maximumEntities; ++index)
    {
        if (m_entityVector[index].getEntityID() == entityID)
        {
            addComponentToEntity(std::make_shared<Entity>(m_entityVector[index]), componentType);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is just a helper function to first find the Entity, then it will call the function below:

```
void EntityManager::addComponentToEntity(std::shared_ptr<Entity> entity, ComponentManager::ComponentType componentType)
{
    if (entity != nullptr)
    {
        switch (componentType)
        {
            case ComponentManager::POSITION:
                entity->addComponent(m_componentManager->getUnassignedPositionComponent());
                break;

    default:
        break;
        }
   }
}
```

This function will find an unassigned (free, available, not added to an Entity) Position component and return it.

```
PositionComponent& ComponentManager::getUnassignedPositionComponent()
{
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < m_positionComponentVector.size(); ++index)
    {
        if (m_positionComponentVector[index].isAssigned() == false)
        {
            m_positionComponentVector[index].assign();
            return m_positionComponentVector[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, inside of Entity we have this function:

```
void Entity::addComponent(Component& component)
{
    m_componentVector.push_back(component);
}
```

The Entities are held inside of a vector inside of EntityManager, created as normal objects on the stack. This is the same for the Position components held inside of ComponentManager.

My aim is to keep all Components inside of ComponentManager and systems make request to ComponentManager to process a component in some way. I want to keep pointers or references for each Entity, to the Components that it owns.

My problem is, once Entity::addComponent() is finished, the m_componentVector vector no longer holds the Component that was added to it, like it is falling out of scope. I think the problem is somewhere I am passing a copy instead of a reference? I originally had the parameters as pointers but was playing around trying to fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to make the `Entity`'s `m_componentVector` hold *references* to the component returned by `getUnassignedPositionComponent()`? You can't store references in a container.

Comment: Just now it is declared as std::vector<Component> m_componentVector, so a vector of Component instances.

Comment: Then you are pushing into the vector a copy of the `Component` (and if `PositionComponent` is a derived class of `Component`, as it seems likely, then the copying also sliced the object).

Comment: Okay that sounds quite likely then, can you describe how I can make sure I am pushing a reference to the Component rather than a copy of it? I'll look into slicing, thanks.

Comment: Instead of storing reference, store index instead. all kind of thing can go bad with reference of element inside vector.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. However, I did have pointers but still have the same issue as I am having now, good to get a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertinent fact from comments: `Entity::m_componentVector` is defined as

```
std::vector<Component> m_componentVector;
```

This is a vector that stores `Component` objects, not references. Thus, in `Entity::addComponent`, the line

```
m_componentVector.push_back(component);
```

will make a copy of the object referenced by `component` and add it to the vector. This copy is independent of the object copied from.

To make it worse, the `component` parameter to `addComponent` actually references an object of type `PositionComponent` (which presumably is derived from `Component`). In making the copy noted above, only the part corresponding to `Component`, the base class, will be copied. This is known as *slicing* - the parts added by the derived class are simply "sliced off".

You want to make Entity's `m_componentVector` reference the components stored in `ComponentManager`. You can't store references in a vector. You can store pointers, but pointers to vector elements can be invalidated if additional elements are added to the vector (that is, if you store a pointer to `m_positionComponentVector[0]`, and later more elements are added to `m_positionComponentVector` such that a reallocation is necessary, the pointer you stored will become invalid). Thus, storing indices is your safest option.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I now realise what exactly is causing the problem. Your suggestion about using an index seems sensible, I thought about this before and thought passing a reference or pointer may be simpler but the problem with that you put forward could certainly cause some headache problems.

I didn't know about slicing, so that's good to know. To advance I think I will edit my code to use indices as apposed to references.

Thanks for your assistance.